# Efficient and Exact Floating-Point Binary Search

Tags: algorithm, math, floating-point

Consider the following binary search for a value greater than `lo`, but less than or equal to `hi`:

```javascript
find(lo: number, hi: number, isTooLow: (testVal: number) => boolean) {
    for(;;) {
        const testVal = between(lo, hi);
        if (testVal <= lo || testVal >= hi) {
            break;
        }
        if (isTooLow(testVal)) {
            lo = testVal;
        } else {
            hi = testVal;
        }
    }
    return hi;
}
```

Note that a `number` here is a 64-bit float.

The search will will always terminate, and if the `between` function is very carefully written to choose the median available 64-bit float between `lo` and `hi`, if it exists, then also:

- The search will terminate within 64 iterations; and
- It will exactly find the smallest value `hi` such that `isTooLow(hi) == false`

But such a `between` function is tricky and complicated, and it depends on the fine details of the floating point representation.

**Can anyone suggest an implementation for `between` that is simpler and that does not depend on any specifics of the floating point representation, except that there is a fixed-width mantissa, a fixed-width exponent, and a sign?**

It will need to be implemented in Javascript, and it only needs to be *almost* as good, such that:

- The search will always terminate within 200 iterations or so; and
- It will very nearly (within 3 or 4 possible values) find the smallest value `hi` such that `isTooLow(hi) == false`

Extra points for avoiding transcendental functions and sqrt.

### RESOLUTION

In the end, I really liked David's stateful guesser, but I hoisted the state up into the call stack, and the result essentially does a search for the exponent first, without any knowledge of the representation.

I haven't tested/debugged this yet:

```js
function find(lo: number, hi: number, isTooLow: (testVal: number) => boolean) {
    [lo, hi] = getLinearRange(lo, hi, isTooLow);
    for (; ;) {
        const testVal = lo + (hi - lo) * 0.5;
        if (testVal <= lo || testVal >= hi) {
            break;
        }
        if (isTooLow(testVal)) {
            lo = testVal;
        } else {
            hi = testVal;
        }
    }
    return hi;
}

/**
 * Reduce a floating-point range to a size where a conventional binary
 * search is appropriate.
 * @returns [newlow, newhigh]
 */
function getLinearRange(
    low: number, high: number,
    isTooLow: (n: number) => boolean): [number, number] {

    let negRange: [number, number] | undefined;
    if (low < 0) {
        if (high > 0) {
            if (isTooLow(0)) {
                return scaleRange(0, high, 0.25, isTooLow);
            } else {
                const isTooHigh = (n: number) => !isTooLow(n);
                negRange = scaleRange(0, -low, 0.25, isTooHigh);
            }
        } else {
            const isTooHigh = (n: number) => !isTooLow(n);
            negRange = scaleRange(-high, -low, 0.25, isTooHigh);
        }
    } else {
        return scaleRange(low, high, 0.25, isTooLow);
    }
    // we have to negate the range
    low = -negRange[1];
    negRange[1] = -negRange[0];
    negRange[0] = low;
    return negRange;
}

/**
 * Reduce a positive range until low/high >= minScale
 * @returns [newlow, newhigh]
 */
function scaleRange(
    low: number, high: number, minScale: number,
    isTooLow: (n: number) => boolean): [number, number] {

    if (!(minScale > 0 && low < high * minScale)) {
        return [low, high];
    }
    const range = scaleRange(low, high, minScale * minScale, isTooLow);
    [low, high] = range;
    const test = high * minScale;
    if (test > low && test < high) {
        if (isTooLow(test)) {
            range[0] = test;
        } else {
            range[1] = test;
        }
    }
    return range;
}
```

Comment: @JohnColeman if the target is near 0, that could take a lot more than 200 iterations to complete. (assuming you meant to compute the mean)

Comment: Yes.  I don't think there's an alternate mathematical definition that makes sense.

Comment: I think a two-phase search, one phase for the exponent, one phase for the mantissa, would satisfy the constraints without being too complicated.

Comment: @user2357112 yes, I'm imagining a `between` function that would have a similar effect.  Also, I'd rather not have to know how many exponent bits there are.

Comment: Start with `testVal = 0` to determine the sign bit. The exponent can be approximated using a search based on the geometric mean. Once you get to the point where `hi < 2 * lo`, you can switch to arithmetic mean to find the mantissa.

Comment: Not really sure how this works out with subnormals. And of course, you do need to know the range of a `number`.

Comment: @user3386109 If nobody writes me a better answer, that's what I'll end up with.  It requires a sqrt() and a bunch of conditions, but otherwise not bad.

Comment: @MattTimmermans For the kind of median or midpoint mentioned in the comment above, you might be interested in my answer to [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/148118/bisecting-intervals-of-floating-point-numbers-containing-0-and-infinity-fairly/150145#150145) on Computer Science SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could also do some precomputation (code below works for nonnegative finite ranges, add branches ad lib to handle the other cases). We approximate the smallest useful fraction, increase it by square roots to effect binary search on the exponent, and then finish off with good old arithmetic mean to nail down the significand. I think the worst case is 65 queries, certainly not much more, though many inputs will take longer than the bit-munging algorithm.

```js
const fractions = [];
const Guesser = {
  fractions: null,
  between(low, high) {
    if (this.fractions === null) {
      this.fractions = [];
      let f = 0.25;
      while (low + f * (high - low) > low) {
        this.fractions.push(f);
        f *= f;
      }
    }
    return low + (this.fractions.pop() || 0.5) * (high - low);
  },
};
for (let i = 0; i <= 101; ++i) {
  let n = 0;
  let g = Object.create(Guesser);
  let low = 0;
  let high = 1.7976931348623157e308;
  for (;;) {
    ++n;
    let mid = g.between(low, high);
    if (mid <= low || high <= mid) break;
    if (100 * Math.random() < i) low = mid;
    else high = mid;
  }
  console.log(n);
}
```

Comment: Another interesting idea.  This reminds me of the Q-coder for arithmetic coding.  I bet we could get the worst case to under 70 iterations by optimizing `between`'s internal state machine.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Yeah, we could squeeze some iterations by using `2**-53 * f`, at the cost of aesthetics and encoding some specific knowledge of the floating point representation.

Comment: This is the idea I went with, although it ended up looking quite different. I added the final implementation to the end of the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s an idea that I think meets your specs on IEEE doubles using primitive operations only (but seems probably worse than using square root assuming that it’s hardware-accelerated). Find the sign (if needed), find the top 7 bits of the 11-bit exponent using linear search (≈ 128 queries, plus 4 for subnormals, ugh), then switch to the arithmetic mean (≈ 53 + 2<sup>11−7</sup> = 69 queries), for a total of about 200 queries if I’m counting right. Untested JavaScript below.

```js
const multiplicative_stride = 1 / 2 ** (2 ** (11 - 7));
function between(low, high) {
  if (high <= 0) return -between(-high, -low);
  if (low < 0) return 0;
  const mid = multiplicative_stride * high;
  return mid <= low ? low + 0.5 * (high - low) : mid;
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting idea.  If I'm parsing this correctly, then the ideal stride does a linear search for the top half of the exponent, and this comes out to 155 iterations or so: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+2%5Ex+%2B+2%5E%2811-x%29+from+4+to+7 .   I'll figure out the optimal 2 and 3-stride versions later.

Answer (score -1):

Using 64 floating iterations is not a good idea because you forgot that [64 bit floats (`double`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) are represented as 3 separated things:

```
1 bit sign
11 bit exponent
53 bit mantissa
```

and if you do not know the real range (where you can start) of the solution then you might be off by quite a few iterations as range of such number is much more then 2^64 ...

However if you do this on binary bits directly then its OK (but you have to handle special cases like `NaN,Inf` and maybe also Denormalized numbers).

So instead of using `*0.5` you use binary operations on individual bits like `x<<=1, x|=1, x^=1` ...

Here simple example C++:

```cpp
double f64_sqrt(double x)
    {
    // IEEE 754 double MSW masks
    const DWORD _f64_sig    =0x80000000;    // sign
    const DWORD _f64_exp    =0x7FF00000;    // exponent
    const DWORD _f64_exp_sig=0x40000000;    // exponent sign
    const DWORD _f64_exp_bia=0x3FF00000;    // exponent bias
    const DWORD _f64_exp_lsb=0x00100000;    // exponent LSB
    const DWORD _f64_man    =0x000FFFFF;    // mantisa
    const DWORD _f64_man_msb=0x00080000;    // mantisa MSB

    const int h=1;      // may be platform dependent MSB/LSB order
    const int l=0;
    DWORD b;            // bit mask
    union               // semi result
        {
        double f;       // 64bit floating point
        DWORD u[2];     // 2x32 bit uint
        } y;
    // fabs
    y.f=x; y.u[h]&=_f64_exp|_f64_man; x=y.f;
    // set safe exponent (~ abs half) destroys mantisa,sign
    b=(y.u[h]&_f64_exp)-_f64_exp_bia;
    y.u[h]=((b>>1)|(b&_f64_exp_sig))+_f64_exp_bia;
    // sign=`+` mantisa=0
    y.u[h]&=_f64_exp;
    // correct exponent if needed
    if (y.f*y.f>x) y.u[h]=(y.u[h]-_f64_exp_lsb)&_f64_exp;
    // binary search
    for (b=_f64_man_msb;b;b>>=1) { y.u[h]|=b; if (y.f*y.f>x) y.u[h]^=b; }
    for (b=0x80000000  ;b;b>>=1) { y.u[l]|=b; if (y.f*y.f>x) y.u[l]^=b; }
    return y.f;
    }
```

using "estimation" of solution exponent (exploiting the fact that result has ~ half of integer bits for sqrt) and binary access binary search of mantissa only (53 iterations)

In case you do not know the exponent range you have to bin search it too (starting from highest bit or one after if sign is known) ...